# How can one load an AppEngine cloud storage backup to a local development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm experimenting with the Google cloud storage backup feature for an application.

After downloading the backup files using gsutil, how can they be loaded into a local development server?

Is there a parser available for these formats (eg, protocol buffers)?

Comment: Are you using python or java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greg Bayer wrote some Python code showing how to do this in a [blog post](http://gbayer.com/big-data/app-engine-datastore-how-to-efficiently-export-your-data/):

```
# Make sure App Engine SDK is available
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine')
from google.appengine.api.files import records
from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
from google.appengine.api import datastore

raw = open('path_to_datastore_export_file', 'r')
reader = records.RecordsReader(raw)
for record in reader:
  entity_proto = entity_pb.EntityProto(contents=record)
  entity = datastore.Entity.FromPb(entity_proto)
  #Entity is available as a dictionary!
```

Comment: *RecordsReader instead of RecordReader

Answer (score 7):

Backups are stored in [leveldb record format](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/log_format.txt), you should be able to read then using:

- [google.api.files.records.RecordsReader](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/records.py&l=273)
- [ext.mapreduce.input_readers.RecordReader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers#RecordsReader)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was looking for exactly this.

Comment: For a complete set of instructions for this approach, see here: https://github.com/Venryx/firestore-leveldb-tools

Answer (score 0):

For those using windows change the open line to:
raw = open('path_to_datastore_export_file', 'rb')

The file must be opened in binary mode!